# Are there polynomials such that $1+xy+(xy)^2+\dots+(xy)^n=f_1(x)g_1(y)+\dots+f_n(x)g_n(y)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n \in \mathbb{R}[y]$. Is it possible that
$$1+xy+(xy)^2+\dots+(xy)^n=f_1(x)g_1(y)+\dots+f_n(x)g_n(y),$$
for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$?

For $n=1,2,3$ it's impossible. And for bigger $n$, there are too many equations for me to handle.

Comment: Please show your proofs that it's impossible for $n=1,2,3$

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$h(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^n f_i(x)g_i(y).$$
If I fix $b\in \Bbb R$ and consider
$$h_b(x)=h(x,b),$$
then
$$h_b(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n c_if_i(x),$$
where $c_i=g_i(b)$. Therefore, all $h_b$ lie in $V$, the vector space
of functions spanned by $f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)$. Certainly $\dim V\le n$.

But if $h(x,y)=1+xy+x^2y^2+\cdots + x^ny^n$, the vector
space spanned by the $h_b(x)$ contains all of $1$, $x$, $x^2,\ldots,x^n$
(why?) and so has dimension $\ge n+1$.

Comment: Hmm... This proof is somewhat suggestive. If we define the rank of a polynomial $p(x,y)$ in $k[x,y]$ to be the minimum $r$ such that $p$ is a sum of $r$ polynomials of the form $a(x)b(y)$,  this proof shows the rank is at least the dimension of the span of $p(x,b) \in k[x]$ as $b$ varies.  Does equality always hold?